# Hiberclipse for eclipse Indigo Service Release 2

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-plugin

I just need a help in configuring hiberclipse for my eclipse indigo version.

Install new software--> added below URL for hibernate plugin and I see no updates , it says there is no site selected...

http://hiberclipse.sourceforge.net/siteupdate.

Any suggestion around would be more appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working...downloaded source manually and placed under eclipse plugins...

THanks